Insert stacks into the queue
I created stacks in c coding language and added to these stacks the word that the user wants from the "dictionary.txt
"
file from the dictionary and added it to the stacks. In this dictionary file, I found words with the same length as the word entered by the user but with a different single letter and added them to the word the user wanted. for each found word, I created separate stacks with the word you want from the user and enqueue them to the queue. Here, I tried to write a program in C programming language that takes a start word and a target word from the user, creates stacks until it reaches this target word, adds them to queues, dequeues the stacks from the queue whether the target word is reached or not, and if the word at the top of the stacks is equal to the target word, pops the words from the stacks and prints each word in the stack. But the program I wrote does not work. Since I am new in this business, I could not find where I am doing wrong. thank you. Here's the following my code:                                                                           `
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE 1000

// Stack yapısı
typedef struct {
    char words[MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    int top;
} Stack;

// Queue yapısı
typedef struct {
    Stack stacks[MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE];
    int front, rear;
} Queue;

// Stack işlemleri
void initStack(Stack *stack) {
    stack->top = -1;
}

int isStackEmpty(Stack *stack) {
    return (stack->top == -1);
}

void push(Stack *stack, char *word) {
    if (stack->top < MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE - 1) {
        stack->top++;
        strcpy(stack->words[stack->top], word);
    } else {
        printf("Stack overflow!\n");
    }
}

char* pop(Stack *stack) {
    if (!isStackEmpty(stack)) {
        return stack->words[stack->top--];
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

// Queue işlemleri
void initQueue(Queue *queue) {
    queue->front = queue->rear = -1;
}

int isQueueEmpty(Queue *queue) {
    return (queue->front == -1);
}

int isQueueFull(Queue *queue) {
    return ((queue->rear + 1) % MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE == queue->front);
}

void enqueue(Queue *queue, Stack stack) {
    if (!isQueueFull(queue)) {
        if (isQueueEmpty(queue)) {
            queue->front = queue->rear = 0;
        } else {
            queue->rear = (queue->rear + 1) % MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE;
        }
        queue->stacks[queue->rear] = stack;
    } else {
        printf("Queue is full!\n");
    }
}

Stack dequeue(Queue *queue) {
    Stack stack;
    if (!isQueueEmpty(queue)) {
        stack = queue->stacks[queue->front];
        if (queue->front == queue->rear) {
            queue->front = queue->rear = -1;
        } else {
            queue->front = (queue->front + 1) % MAX_DICTIONARY_SIZE;
        }
        return stack;
    } else {
        printf("Queue is empty!\n");
        initStack(&stack); // Boş bir stack döndür
        return stack;
    }
}

// Sözlük dosyasından kelime okuma işlemi
void readDictionary(Stack *stack, char *filename, char *userWord) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Dictionary file not found!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF) {
        if (strlen(word) == strlen(userWord)) {
            int diff = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
                if (word[i] != userWord[i]) {
                    diff++;
                }
            }
            if (diff == 1) {
                push(stack, word);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    char startWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH], targetWord[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    printf("Enter the start word: ");
    scanf("%s", startWord);
    printf("Enter the target word: ");
    scanf("%s", targetWord);

    Queue queue;
    initQueue(&queue);

    Stack startStack;
    initStack(&startStack);
    push(&startStack, startWord);
    enqueue(&queue, startStack);

    while (!isQueueEmpty(&queue)) {
        Stack currentStack = dequeue(&queue);
        char *currentWord = pop(&currentStack);

        if (strcmp(currentWord, targetWord) == 0) {
            printf("Path found!\n");
            printf("Transformation path: ");
            while (!isStackEmpty(&currentStack)) {
                char *word = pop(&currentStack);
                printf("%s -> ", word);
            }
            printf("%s\n", startWord);
            break;
        }

        readDictionary(&currentStack, "dictionary.txt", currentWord);

        for (int i = 0; i <= currentStack.top; i++) {
            Stack newStack = currentStack;
            enqueue(&queue, newStack);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


I want to make sure that the dictionary reading logic correctly identifies words that differ by one letter from each other and that I use them appropriately to create new paths.

Hi - welcome to stackoverflow.  Please be more specific than "doesn't work."  Ie: What was the expected output, and what was the actual output?  Please edit your question to say... thanks.

Queue queue; Your struct Stack is ~50,000 bytes large. Queue takes 1,000 Stacks, i.e. ~50,000,000 bytes. It is very likely that this does not fit in your stack. Make it a gobal variable, a static variable or use dynamic memory allocation for it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Aside from the wrong storage class of queue mentioned by Gerhardh, the major mistake in the program is that currentStack (where the Transformation path is to be collected) is also used in readDictionary and thereby overwritten. Another error is that currentWord is removed from currentStack, despite the word may be needed for the transformation. And a last one is that the same newStack is enqueued repeatedly, rather than several times with an added word from the dictionary. So, the core of the loop could be changed like:
        if (strcmp(currentWord, targetWord) == 0) {
            printf("Path found!\n");
            printf("Transformation path: ");
            printf("%s", currentWord);
            while (!isStackEmpty(&currentStack)) {
                char *word = pop(&currentStack);
                printf(" <- %s", word);
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }

        push(&currentStack, currentWord);   // we still need the word
        // and we still need the stack - don't abuse it for the dictionary
        readDictionary(&startStack, "dictionary.txt", currentWord);
        while (currentWord = pop(&startStack))
        {
            Stack newStack = currentStack;
            push(&newStack, currentWord);   // only one new word on each stack
            enqueue(&queue, newStack);
        }

